# How To Create Dropdowns in Bootstrap with Array?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm looking for help with populating a drop down under each state.
The states with more counties messes up the flow of the rows and columns.

Code pasted below from home.blade.php:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
            @foreach ($areas as $country)
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3><a href="{{ route('user.area.store', $country) }}">{{ $country->name }}</a></h3>
                    <hr>

                    <div class="row">
                        @foreach ($country->children as $state)
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h4><a href="{{ route('user.area.store', $state) }}">{{ $state->name }}</a></h4>
                                <hr>

                                @foreach ($state->children as $city)
                                    <h5><a href="{{ route('user.area.store', $city) }}">{{ $city->name }}</a></h5>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

Comment: I don't see any drop-down.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3? There is no panel in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Oh, I guess I am on Bootstrap 3 :s